# retrieve Xml data from database into my page

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data into an xml tag from the database using a stored procedure. I want to create the reponse like standard xml responses. But instead I am getting a tag named: `<NewDataSet/>`

This is my code for retrieving data:

```
comm = new SqlCommand("[sp_get_business_locations]", conn);
    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", Latitude);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", Longitude);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();    
cdoc.LoadXml(shop.GetXml());
```

What can be done? Thanks.

```
DataSet shop = new DataSet();
XmlDocument cdoc = new XmlDocument();
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
SElECT  @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM HeritageList   
 INNER JOIN  Reviews loc  WITH (NOLOCK) ON HeritageList.HeritageId = loc.HeritageId    
 WHERE ([dbo].[DistanceBetween] (@Latitude,@Longitude,Latitude,Longitude)) * @meters <= @Radius      
        
    IF(@TotalRows>0)    
    BEGIN    
         DECLARE @Partialxml XML      
     DECLARE @Totalxml XML      
     declare @Appendxml VARCHAR(100)       
     SET @Appendxml = '<HeritageList></HeritageList>';      
     set @Totalxml=@Appendxml      
         
     SET @Partialxml = (SELECT  HeritageList.HeritageId,
           
        
         
        Latitude as "Location/Latitude",      
        Longitude as "Location/Longitude",      
        Country as "Location/Country",      
        [State] as "Location/State",      
        City as "Location/City",      
        Postcode as "Location/Postcode",      
        [Address] as "Location/Address",     
        (Cast(Round((( [dbo].[DistanceBetween]           
         (@Latitude,@Longitude,Latitude,Longitude)) * @meters),2,1) as decimal(18,2))) as Distance    
        FROM dbo.HeritageList  INNER JOIN  Reviews loc   WITH (NOLOCK) ON HeritageList.HeritageId = loc.HeritageId    
        WHERE ([dbo].[DistanceBetween] (@Latitude,@Longitude,Latitude,Longitude)) * @meters <= @Radius     
          FOR XML PATH('Business'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)      
     SET @Totalxml.modify('insert sql:variable("@Partialxml")  as last into (/HeritageList)[1] ' )      
      
     SELECT @Totalxml      
 END    
    
END
```

Comment: What are cdoc and shop? Where do you execute the command? I suspect the last line has nothing to do with the sql command and you are looking at some existing values instead of the command's results. You have to execute comm.ExecuteScalar or comm.ExecuteReader if you want to retrieve the results

Comment: Can you share your stored procedure.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I have edited it.. i am trying your suggestions.. thanks again

Comment: Shall I put ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery? I did it but still I am getting <NewDataSet/> in result

Comment: Side-note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your SQL Server stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for their own use - just use something else.

Comment: I have updated the question with my stored procedure.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the DataAdapter,

```
SqlDataAdapter adpater=new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataSet shop=new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(shop);

XmlDocument cdoc = new XmlDocument();
cdoc.LoadXml(shop.GetXml());
```